# Check for Null while Creating XML document from object list

Tags: xml, linq, object, null

I want to create an XML document from object list. How to handle Null in the  transform.

```
  XElement xml = new XElement("people",
                            from p in PPL
                            select new XElement("person",
                                        new XElement("id", p.ID),
                                        new XElement("firstname", p.FirstName),
                                        new XElement("lastname", p.LastName),
                                        new XElement("idrole", p.IDRole)));
```

As shown in the above example if the **PPL** is null then my xml should have just <\people>  Now I am getting NUllreferenc error.

Thanks in advance
BB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the null coalescing operator:

```
from p in PPL ?? Enumerable.Empty<Person>()
```

If you need to do this for a collection of an anonymous type, you could create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> EmptyIfNull<TSource>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<TSource>();
}
```

then your query could use

```
from p in PPL.EmptyIfNull()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jon.Thats works great. In addition to the above question say if p.ID == null then I see <id /> but I don't want to see <id /> how can i eliminate it from my XML if p.id == null.

Comment: @BumbleBee: It sounds like you want something like `p.ID == null ? null : new XElement("id", p.ID)`. LINQ to XML will ignore null references when constructing the tree.

Comment: In the extension method I get the error : "The type or namespace name 'TSource' cannot be found" at the line of code return soucre?? Enumerable.Empty<Tsource>();

Comment: @Bumblebee: Oops, forgot to make the method generic. Fixed now.